# Is this a common side effect when using a headless CMS/Prismic?

Tags: nuxt.js, content-management-system, headless, prismic

Right now, I'm trying to understand how a headless CMS works in Nuxt 3, so I've started experimenting with Prismic.

Let's say I create a reusable component that fetch data from a remote source, which we can call X, that takes in a headline and uses it across multiple pages simultaneously, where different headlines are used.

Let's also say that my website has three pages, and on the homepage, component X should have the headline "Welcome," on the second page the headline "About Me," and on the third page the headline "Contact." What I've noticed is that when I click on any page, I briefly see the previous headline flash before the current one is displayed.

To illustrate this, I used a pre-made template from the Prismic website where I didn't write any code myself (click on the blog posts)

https://lalalala-two.vercel.app/

My question is: Is this a common phenomenon when using a headless CMS or is this just related to Prismic?